# Containing Properly children with margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I am creating template with buttons.

My problem is simple yet painful. **I can't seem to make all of the children elements to perfectly fit each parent elements while making some space in-between elements at the same time**

I do not want to use :first-child, :last-child selector

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7b8snh5e/

Here is my structure

HTML

```
<div class="button-container">
     <div class="button-row">
           <div class="button-single">
               <span>Button 1</span>
           </div>
     </div>
     <div class="button-row">
           <div class="button-double">
               <span>Button 2</span>
           </div>
           <div class="button-double">
               <span>Button 3</span>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button-container{
    margin-top:5%;
    height:45%;
}
.button-row{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    max-height:50%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    padding:5px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row div{
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000ccc;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row span{
    font-size:1rem;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.button-single{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px 5px;
    height:100%
}
.button-double{
    width:50%;
    margin:0px 5px;
    height:100%;
}
.button-footer{
    margin-top:2%;
    height:8%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

When I set padding to each row container for row space,
the whole wrap contains its child well

[image: button container]

but, single button element overflows its parent element(button row)

[image: button row container]

if I change `padding:5px 0` to `margin:5px 0` on button-row
button row seems to contain its child well.

[image]

but now the problem is that row elements overflows its parent

[image]

what am i missing here?

I do not want any child element overflowing any parent element.

Comment: can you explain a bit more please. if possible draw your expected answer

Comment: I expect no child element overflowing its parent element, contained only in blue area in developer console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.button-container{
    margin-top: 5%;
      /* problem here 
    height:45%;*/
}
.button-row{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row div{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000ccc;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row span{
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.button-single{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.button-double{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.button-footer{
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 8%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="button-container">
   <div class="button-row">
     <div class="button-single">
       <span>Button 1</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="button-row">
     <div class="button-double">
       <span>Button 2</span>
     </div>
     <div class="button-double">
       <span>Button 3</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You have fixed height on your button container that why your child got 100% height with margin will go out of the box !

Comment: this was the closest result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `height` from `.button-single, .button-double` and setting `margin: 5px;` there itself and removed `margin`/`padding` from `.button-row` as well.

Hope it will solve your problem.

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.button-container{
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 45%;
}
.button-row{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row div{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000ccc;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-row span{
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.button-single, .button-double {
  margin: 5px;
}
.button-single{
    width: 100%;
}
.button-double{
    width: 50%;
}
.button-footer{
    margin-top: 2%;
    height: 8%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="button-container">
   <div class="button-row">
     <div class="button-single">
       <span>Button 1</span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="button-row">
     <div class="button-double">
       <span>Button 2</span>
     </div>
     <div class="button-double">
       <span>Button 3</span>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button-row{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.button-single{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Use heights and width in percentage % do not fix it in pixels